# How to auto-remove html closing tags (like in intellij)

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

In intellij, if you have:

`<slot></slot>`

and you want to remove the closing tag, you simple can add `/` to the opening tag and it transforms it into:

`<slot/>`

Is there a way to do that in `vscode` or something similar?

Comment: you mean modify the tag after it has been created? At creation if you use `/>` I'm pretty sure that vscode won't automatically create a closing tag

Comment: write an extension to do this